# Is it possible to uninstall the 'programs' rm, cp and mv from the system?

Tags: coreutils

I can't see how this would be useful, but I'm really interested.

Is it possible to uninstall the programs `rm`, `cp` and `mv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those programs are part of the package **coreutils**, which is depended upon by so many packages, that while you *could*  force your package manager to uninstall it, it would break your whole system and thus is utterly pointless.

**tl;dr**: Don't even try.

Answer (score 4):

All the Ubuntu meta-packages, all the way down to `ubuntu-minimal` indirectly depend on `coreutils` (which these are part of)... There isn't really to properly uninstall them because everything else needs them.

And what's to stop somebody bringing their own tools? I could, for example, write a version of `cp` in Python in a few minutes. If you're trying to lock things down, it might make most sense to ask yourself "What damage *could* this user do?" then fixing that rather than papering over the holes with obscurity.

If you need certain files to not be damaged, fix their permissions. You've got a few options:

- [Mount them as readonly from another location](http://lwn.net/Articles/281157/)
- Make them owned by a different account and give global read access (`chmod 744` for example)
- Use `acl` (access control list - like the chmod permission on steroids) for granular permissions over lots of users)
- Imaging and reimaging on reboot and netbooting to restore to a known-working system on boot.

You can use a lot of this stuff together but chances are if you remove something (aside from the technical arguments) you're just inconveniencing the people that really need the tools. Those with nefarious intentions are more than well equipped enough to work around simple blocks.